# Getting error on using IP address - "The security certificate presented by this website was issued for a different website's address."

Tags: https, ssl-certificate, ip-address, dmz

I have hosted my software product (Say SoftPro) on one the servers (say Server1). This SoftPro is a web application with Https with Self signed  certificate. The  server is in Demiliterized zone (DMZ). So, from client machines, I cannot use server name to access my software product. Instead, I need to use servers IP address (Like- https://10.20.30.40/SoftPro).

But when I do this, I get a certificate error saying - "**The security certificate presented by this website was issued for a different website's address**". Even if I install the certificate and re-open the browser, the issue still exists. This issue is there when I use https://localhost/SoftPro on the server itself.

I tried adding this to Trusted site. I also tried redirecting IP address to hostname by adding IP address and its DNS name to Hosts file in C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc. If I open the browser with https://10.20.30.40/SoftPro, it doesnt redirect and it still gives me same error.

Any workaround for resolve this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you added the IP address -> domain name in your Windows hosts file, then you would use the domain name to access the server instead of the IP address.

Comment: Thanks. But even then, i think it works only within the server. But how to solve certificate error when I access https://10.20.30.40/SoftPro from clients outside DMZ?

Comment: You can modify the /etc/hosts file on any system.